# Vertically center text in text input in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer

I am having trouble vertical aligning text in an input field in Internet Explorer.

I have:

```
input#search {
    float:left;
    font-size:11px;
    height:20px;
    margin:0;
    padding-left:4px;
    width:100px;
}
```

In Firefox and Chrome, it seems to be automatically vertical aligned, however in Internet Explorer it is not.

Comment: Im having the same issue and changing the input height and line-height has no effect on anything.

Answer (score 45):

Just set the height and line-height for the input object and it works fine (ie 7+).

```
input { border: 0; font-size: 0.8em; height: 32px; line-height: 32px;}
```

gl
Paulo Bueno

Comment: It's always about the line-height :)

Comment: Best cross-browser solution imo.

Answer (score 8):

Just define `line-height` and `height` for a text box with same value. It will be taken care

Answer (score 1):

You can use IE conditional comment like this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
input#search{
  padding-top:3px;    /* adjust value */
}
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `line-height:1` might mitigate the vertical alignment and a bit of `padding:.15em`  should add some breathing space to the fields too.

Answer (score -1):

Check the parent div. If it's empty you need to add content (&nbps;) so explorer will calc the height correctly.