# show label text in multiple lines

Tags: css, asp.net, label, line-breaks, multiline

I have a label inside a radgrids item template. I assign text to it in item databound.
I want my text for  label to appear vertically like this:

```
T
M
```

I tried  like this

```
label.Text="T" & vbCrLf & "M"
```

and like this

```
label.Text="T" &"<br/>"&"M"
```

It really is a very short text. Possible values for label are TM,TR,TP and TS. I set the width to 1px and height to 10 px for that label. 
Can this be done?If you need more info,please ask. Thanks

EDIT: I did it like this and it worked in chrome,firefox and safari but NOT in IE(version 11)

```
label.Text = "T" & Environment.NewLine & "M"
```

Comment: May be the link [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/multiline-radtextbox-new-line-does-not-display-in-ie) might help you on the IE11 issue.

Comment: @DennisR. Thanks, but it did not work. Also my control is a label.

Comment: I found the solution here for IE: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153082/vertical-align-text-in-input-in-internet-explorer

Answer (score -2):

its matter of slash in br your slash  should before br

Comment: This is blatantly wrong and will produce invalid (working, but still invalid) HTML.